# MySQL Database return null result

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-functions

When Use 'SELECT' command in MySQL From node js. Sometimes the query returns a non null value and sometimes returns null with the same query

Here is my code:

```
exports.Top10 = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Ads ORDER BY (Stars / Raters) LIMIT 10", function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Top10 Err: ", err);
        }
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

> Top10 Err:  { Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
>
> ```
> at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:201:16)
> at Protocol._enqueue (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:139:13)
> at Connection.query (/user_code/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:25)
> at /user_code/index.js:510:28
> at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:41)
> at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:671:7
> at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:655:9
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
> at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9) code:
> ```
>
> 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }

I'm using `Firebase` Cloud Functions as Node Server & `Amazon RDS MySQL` For Database

If you have any questions about this issue please leave a comment

Comment: Your connection is dead due to a previous error or loss of connection.  It's not returning a null result -- it's not executing, because queries cannot be enqueued for execution after a fatal error.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot What can I do to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

when use to order then apply to desc/asc, will have use to this code

```
exports.Top10 = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM Ads ORDER BY (Stars / Raters) DESC LIMIT 10", function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Top10 Err: ", err);
        }
        res.end(JSON.Parse(result));
    });
});
```